# How to fix KeyError: '33'

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to Python.
A table (pressure_2) was imported into jupyter notebook, and for this table (shown below), the name of each column is a number.

```
Timestamp      1         2        3          4        ....           33

0.000          28.92    33.87      37.13     37.13   ....            48.50

0.083          28.94    33.89      37.16     37.23   ....            48.54

0.167          28.96    33.91      37.18     37.21   ....            48.56
....
```

Then, I checked are there some missing values in each column using code `pressure_2.isna().sum()` and it shows in column 33, there are 445 missing values. So I was going to use code `pressure_2['33'].fillna(pressure_2['33'].mean(),inplace=True)` to handle these missing values, but it returns a error (KeyError: '33').

I appreciate a lot if any advices.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your column name type is not string. Convert headers' type to string by

```py
df.columns = df.columns.map(str)
```

Then access the column with

```py
pressure_2['33']
# or
pressure_2.iloc[:, '33']
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to check all the keys in your dict:

```
print(pressure_2.keys())
```

maybe the right key is number 33 instead of string 33

Comment: I have checked all the keys and I found that dtype of 33 is object . So could you please give me a clue of how to solve it?